# How to cover up exposed underfloor after removing interior closet walls?

Tags: repair, floor, threshold

Happy New Year, All!
I'm close (I think) to wrapping up an attempt at a built-in closet, but am having trouble figuring out a way to cover up two floor positions that were exposed when I removed part of the pre-existing closet wall (see pictures).

[image]

I am exploring the use of a wooden threshold (see in pictures - not stained yet), but wanted to see if the community had any other ideas.

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Simple, easy, and should look good.  Why make more work.

Comment: Threshold good. If it was somewhere other than a closet, I’d want to consider the bigger picture…

Comment: For this question from what I see, you can make your solution as a answer.  Quite right to answer your own question.

Comment: Only other idea I could give is to steal boards from other closets or areas that are closed/covered up.  Otherwise the threshold looks fine to me—or it will once you stain it to match(ish) the floor.